# Meteor : "console" variable undefined inside require call

Tags: meteor, npm, webrtc, peerjs, temasys

I'm facing a strange problem on Meteor and I can't resolve it :

I'm developping a WebRTC app using Meteor, PeerJS and AdapterJS (which give an WebRTC plugin for unsupported browser like Safari or IE). These two libs are downloaded using NPM : meteor npm install peerjs/adapterjs

So in my view's controller I have :

> view.js

```
//import Peer from 'peerjs'; => same error with "import"
//import AdapterJS from 'adapterjs';
Template.view.onRendered(function(){

    AdapterJS = require("adapterjs");
    Peer = require("peerjs");
    //var peerkey="..."
    var peer = new Peer({
      key: peerkey,  // get a free key at http://peerjs.com/peerserver
      debug: 3,
      config: {'iceServers': [
        { url: 'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302' },
        { url: 'stun:stun1.l.google.com:19302' },
      ]}
    });
```

But when I run my controller, I get an exception because "console" is undefined inside peerjs/util.js function when calling the peerjs constructor :

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'log' of undefined

Strangly, when I only require "peerjs", there is no exeption...
I tried to change the order of require functions but it won't work.
Other variable like "alert", "window.console" work and are defined inside the module but "console" not.. :/

Any suggestion can help ^^

Thanks in advance.

EDIT : If I add a breakpoint on the first line of node_module/peerjs/lib/util.js, I see that the "console" variable is "undefined" inside util.js but .... it is defined inside the caller function (fileEvaluate) !

EDIT2 : I tried something else to check if the code inside adapterjs redefine or change something : I put 'require("adapterjs")'  inside a timeout function with a long delay (10 seconds) and .... console is still undefined inside peer module ! But when I comment require("adapterjs"), no error, console is defined ! I think that Meteor do something special before running the controller script depending on require functions...

EDIT3 : Here is a git repo to test the project : [gitlab.com](https://gitlab.com/arsenalol69/exemple-adapterjs-peerjs)
If you display the dev console, you will see exceptions.

Comment: Is something redefining console? I use peerjs myself so no probs there - perhaps it is in adapterJS?

Comment: I don't know if it will help, but Meteor recommend the use of `import` and not `require`. Try moving your import at the beginning of your file, before the `Template.view.onRendered()`:
`import AdapterJs from 'adapterjs'`
`import Peer from 'peerjs'`

Comment: @MikeKing When I use only peerJS, it's working... so maybe adapterJS does something wrong...

Comment: @MaxG. I tried your solution but the same error in (node_modules/peerjs/lib/util.js), even if I change the order... xD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, although I don't fully understand it myself. It's something to do with the way that Meteor imports modules, and Peerjs runs afoul of that.

Basically I copied node_modules/peerjs/dist/peer.js into the client directory, so that Meteor will load it "as is".

A small change to main.js as follows:

```
import './main.html';

// I placed peer.js from the node_modules/peerjs/dist/peer.js into the client folder and it works fine
// import {Peer} from 'peerjs';
import {AdapterJS as Adapter} from 'adapterjs';

Template.hello.onCreated(function helloOnCreated() {
    // counter starts at 0

    window.peer = new Peer({
```

and it works fine :)

Comment: Thanks for your solution Mikkel ! :) I also use a similar solution : I import AdapterJS with `$('head').append('<script src="/adapter.min.js"><\/script>');` The two solutions work great. I will also post a message in meteor forum to see if they can resolve the issue !

Comment: Have you got this to work in Safari? It's telling me that webRTC isn't supported, even with loading adapter as you suggested and loading the temasys webrtc plugin

Comment: Last year, I developed an NPM  application wich works in Safari and IE9 using the temasys plugin and SimpleWebRTC in the same way and it works great ;)

Comment: That's impressive. I tried the Temasys plugin yesterday with adapterJS and it just hangs Safari. if I remove adapterjs it runs up but tells me webRTC is not supported, I'm not sure how to get round that one.

Comment: First, just try to display of your webcam using only AdapterJS :
`AdapterJS.webRTCReady(function(isUsingPlugin) {
 //Start webcam and microphone :
     navigator.getUserMedia({audio:true, video: true}, function (stream) {
         //display video
         var video = document.getElementById("myVideo");
        video.src = URL.createObjectURL(stream);
         window.localStream = stream;
       },
       function (error) { console.log(error); }
     );
});`
Then you can try to use the stream object with your webrct lib (simplewebrtc or peerjs)

Comment: Hey @Arsenalol69 - would you have a meteor project you could share with simplewebrtc ? I need to get serious there now, the boss reckons apple support is top priority now

Answer (score 0):

I see in line 860+ of adapter.js that console is being defined (part of the shim) from https://github.com/Temasys/AdapterJS/blob/master/source/adapter.js

```
// IE 9 is not offering an implementation of console.log until you open a console
if (typeof console !== 'object' || typeof console.log !== 'function') {
    /* jshint -W020 */
    console = {} || console;
    // Implemented based on console specs from MDN
    // You may override these functions
    console.log = function (arg) {};
    console.info = function (arg) {};
    console.error = function (arg) {};
```

This code defines the console if it doesn't find one to it's liking? Does this mean you are using IE9 or some other incompatible browser?

Try pasting this into your console and see what it tells you:

```
if (typeof console !== 'object' || typeof console.log !== 'function') alert("Console not present, needs to be shimmed?"); else console.log("console is ok");
```

Presumably the reason you are using adapter.js is for compatibility purposes - this will help you trouble shoot it. Please let me know what you find, as I will be following you down this path :)

Comment: All modern browsers implement a console object... this section exists to polyfill that missing objects into older browsers that to no feature this built-in and prevent them from producing a JS error.

More information on console support can be found here
http://caniuse.com/#feat=console-basic

More information on the polyfill idea
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyfill

Comment: I'm using Chrome in fact. I tried something yesterday with 'timeout' and give me unexpected result ! Please see my edit2 and thanks for your help :)

Comment: @Arsenalol69 can you share your meteor project and I can have a look? The behaviour is very strange

Comment: @Mikkel please see EDIT3, I created a git repo to test the project :)